# How to save a photoshop image after changing color channel visibility

Tags: image-processing, colors, photoshop, channel

I was messing around with the RGB channels in photoshop and found what I wanted when I removed visibility of the red channel, and kept blue and green. When I went to save my image it saved it in complete RGB. How do I temporarily remove the red channel from the image for saving? I have attached a pic for help. Thanks,

Before,
[image]

How I want it saved,
[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the usage of photoshop program. SuperUser is more suitable

Answer (score 5):

**By definition** if you are working with typical RGB images you have 3 channels of colors. You cannot erase one channel, keep the rest two channels and still have a valid image (in the strict RGB sense). 
**If you need to eliminate the information in one channel** you just have to **turn it to black**. In your case, if you need to eliminate channel Red, then just select the Red channel and fill it completely with black color (ex. use the bucket fill with 255 tolerance). You will still end up with a 3-channel (or 4-channel if you have transparency) image but without any information from the Red channel.

Comment: @cameron-roberson did you try the solution? Is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

i think you probably have the answer by this time but for the others.

after hide the unwanted channels click on image select all with CTRL+A then copy with CTRL+C and create a new layer paste it with CTRL+V and you're done!

Answer (score -2):

I have a solution but it's not recommended:

1. Goto Adobe: *View/Screen Mode/Full screen mode*.
2. On the keyboard press <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>.
3. In Adobe open new file or press <kbd>Ctrl+N</kbd> and make settings as you want.

   **Tip:** For high resolution, change Resolution to higher than 300 and press <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> and you are done.
4. Crop or Resize your picture and save it.

   **Tip:** Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> while resizing to keep the picture in its original condition!